# Find source of computed style in chrome/firefox developer console area?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having some issues with an element being a lot taller than it should be, and when I inspect it in Chrome, in the "styles" box, there is no rules for it other than `min-height: 100%;`.  When I look in the "computed styles" area, it says `height: 854px;` but it won't allow me any way to see where this is being set.

As you can see in the picture below `line-height` has a magnifying glass and isn't grayed out, however height is grayed out and I'm unable to dig into it.  Is there a way to find the source of this setting without having to go through every file piece by piece?

[image]

Comment: in my experience, these properties come from a parent. Try looking through parent elements for the save property that is not grayed out.(ex. if you look at this page, I cannot see `width` of a `<p>` within `<div class = "post-text">` but I can see the width of `<div class="post-text">`. These widths are the same.

Comment: By default, height is not inherited from parent elements. I suppose that it's positioned absolutely and the intended relevant parent is mistakenly positioned staticly, so this one refers to a higher parent.
But that's just wild guessing without more context.